# MySQL DECIMAL(3,2) trailing zeros not showing

Tags: mysql, formatting, decimal, zero

[image]How can I get trailing zeros for type DECIMAL(3,2) to show?

For example, if I insert value 1.50, queries show it as 1.5 instead. See screenshot below. The schema is on the left, the query is on the right, and the results are displayed at the bottome. Thanks!

Comment: We need more information - like what language are you using? How are you trying to display the results? What have you tried so far? If you have example code - add it as an edit to your question, not as a comment - it doesn't format nicely in a comment.

Comment: Updated with screenshot and a little more detail.

Comment: That is an issue with SQLFiddle display, in MySQL workbench the data is displayed with the correct number of dps. As Tim states below, the values are stored to 2dp - it is up to the application displaying the data on how it is displayed. If you are extracting the data & displaying yourself then it is up to you how to display it and that will be language dependant.

Comment: It may not be an issue with the SQLFiddle display, when you view the plain text sql output in SQLFiddle, we also see the same results which are missing the correct precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about what you observe in MySQL directly, it should first be noted that even though the trailing zeros may be missing in the query output, the precision internally should not be affected.

If you want to retain the full width of the `DECIMAL`, you can try either of the following:

```
SELECT CAST(UNIT_PRICE AS CHAR)
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(UNIT_PRICE)
```